# How to perform streamwriter in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I use this code in my VB.Net application

```
Protected Sub btnBHNas_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnBHNasBackup.Click

    'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch\backupbhnas.bat")
    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\backupbhnas.bat", True)

        writer.WriteLine("@echo off")
        writer.WriteLine(" echo ""Specify username""")
        writer.WriteLine("set /p Name=")
        writer.WriteLine("net use k: ""\\backups\back-ups""")
        writer.WriteLine("mkdir k:\%name%")
        writer.WriteLine("set drive=K:\%name%")
        writer.WriteLine("set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y")
        writer.WriteLine("echo ### Backing up My Documents...")
        writer.WriteLine("%backupcmd% ""C:\Documents and Settings\%name%\My Documents"" ""%drive%\My Documents""")
        writer.WriteLine("echo ### Backing up Favorites...")
        writer.WriteLine("%backupcmd% ""C:\Documents and Settings\%name%\Favorites"" ""%drive%\Favorites""")
        writer.WriteLine("echo ### Backing up Desktop...")
        writer.WriteLine("%backupcmd% ""C:\Documents and Settings\%name%\desktop"" ""%drive%\desktop""")
        writer.WriteLine("net use k: /delete")
        writer.WriteLine("echo Backup Complete!")
        writer.WriteLine("pause")

    End Using

    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myDir As String = "C:\"
    For Each myFile In Directory.GetFiles(myDir, "backupbhnas.bat")
        File.Delete(myFile)
    Next

End Sub
```

and it works.  However, when I use it in a button in ASP.Net it does nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: I assume this is running on the machine that has the files you want to back up.  Is that assumption correct?  And have you tried stepping through the code?  Also, at no point are you actually executing the batch file, you're just writing it out.

Comment: Also, this looks like an overly complext solution to a simple task.  Why not just create the batch file, leave it in place, and call it from your program instead of creating and recreating it in code?  It's a heck of a lot easier to maintain a batch file in Notepad (or any other text editor) than in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to write file in C drive your application may need administrative rights(Under Vista and beyond). Check your exceptions and it will help you to find exact issue.

```
Try

    //code 

Catch ex As Exception

   // check exception if any

End Try
```